# signInWithCredential returns null without any error in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase to sign in with phone number it does send OTP message but when I'm trying to sign with credentials using the OTP I got and the verification ID (they're not null they do have values) it returns null here (result is null) not throwing any errors
here's my code

```
 static Future<UserCredential?> verifyOTP(
      String verificationId, String otp) async {
    UserCredential? result;
    try {
      print(otp);
      print(verificationId);

      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: otp,
      );
      result = await _firebaseAuth?.signInWithCredential(credential);
      User? user = _firebaseAuth?.currentUser;
      print('user $user');
      print('results $result');
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: i'm facing a similar issue with Google signin. When I try this:

gCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                  .signInWithCredential(error.credential!);

I get an error as below: 
Error: Unexpected null value.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:51335/dart_sdk.js:5241:11)
    at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:51335/dart_sdk.js:5556:30)

This was working fine earlier before I upgraded Flutter to v 3.3.8 and corresponding packages. These are the new packages

  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.2
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By `signInWithCredential` do you mean `Email and Password` Firebase Authentication?

If so you should use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` Firebase Auth method.
Example below:

```
try {
  await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password,
  );
} catch (_) {
  throw const LogInWithEmailAndPasswordFailure();
}
```

Comment: No I mean to sign with a phone number